# soapui update json request from script

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I can't find any solution for my issue. Many I've tried doesn't work. Could someone help me?

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
"device": {
  "sdk_revision": "dev",
  "sdk_type": "android",
  "app_id": "0518101906",
  "app_version": "0.0.0"
},
"request": {}
}
```

in my request step in soapUI (RestProject).

I'd like to change the `app_id` value in this JSON, so in my groovy script I do:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def today = new Date()
appId = today.format("MMddHHmmss")

def extractSelectionJson(String from) {
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def holderData = slurper.parseText(context.expand('${'+ from +'#Request}'))

appIdKey = holderData["device"]["app_id"]
appIdKey = appId
}

extractSelectionJson("SessionCreate")`
```

`appId` changed only locally, at my json request I have still `"app_id": "0518101906"` although I've tried `setPropertyValue()`, `updateProperty()` (maybe not right way).

Answer (score 2):

For something simple like this, you can use just a one-liner:

```
{
  "device": {
    "sdk_revision": "dev",
    "sdk_type": "android",
    "app_id": "${=String.format('%tm%td%tH%tM%tS'
        , new Date()
        , new Date()
        , new Date()
        , new Date()
        , new Date())}",
    "app_version": "0.0.0"
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

If you need details for the `String.format()`, it is in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Formatter.html).